# Cache webdav request using Workbox

Tags: service-worker, webdav, workbox, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to implement a service worker using Workbox for webdav requests.  However I cannot cache those requests whose request method says PROPFIND.

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
new RegExp('http://xxxx/remote.php/webdav/(.*)'),
workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
    plugins: [
        new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({
            statuses: [0, 200]
        })
    ]
  })
);
```

They are not being cached when I look for cached requests in Cache Storage. 
So how do I register these routes and cache their responses using Service Workers?

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: @Evert Sorry. I wasn't being clear. I edited the question such that it directly reflects a question.